# Potential Error in Forge Post Job Docs with destination

Tags: autodesk-forge

Looking at the documentation for the [Forge Post Job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/). The examples show that region is a sub object of destination. However the docs seem to show that they are on the same level.

Doc was uploaded as image.

Curl Request Example:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
 [![enter image description here][2]][2]-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer PtnrvrtSRpWwUi3407QhgvqdUVKL'
 -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
 -d
  '{
     "input": {
       "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA",
       "compressedUrn": true,
       "rootFilename": "A5.iam"
     },
     "output": {
       "destination": {
         "region": "us"
       },
       "formats": [
         {
           "type": "svf",
           "views": [
             "2d",
             "3d"
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this.

I've let our Dev Portal team know to take a look and will get back to you once they fix this up. Thanks!